# Link Realm within a dynamic library ends in "ld: framework not found Realm for architecture i386"

Tags: realm, dynamic-library, swift2, xcode7.1

I've created a custom dynamic library (let's call in **LogLibrary.framework**) in Swift 2.1. No I'd like to link the *Realm.framework* and *RealmSwift.framework* with it.

I did follow the installation instructions provided on https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/.

These steps are:

- Link Binary with Libraries (*Realm.framework* and *RealmSwift.framework* added)
- Build Phase -> Add copy files Phase -> Destination "Frameworks"
- Run Script Phase -> bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Realm.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"

[image]

Unfortionally, if l link the **LogLibrary.framework** in my sample Application, I always get the following compile error:

> ld: framework not found Realm for architecture i386

I did not set any additional linker flags in the sample Application.

[image]

However, It works if I also link the *Realm.framework* and *RealmSwift.framework* in the sample Application - but that's not what I want, because they are already linked within the **LogLibrary.framework**

Any Ideas how I can get rid of the compile error?
Sample Project: https://github.com/sehdich/RealmLinkError.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should link Realm and RealmSwift.framework to PhotoApp target too. Because those frameworks are not static libraries. They are linked dynamically. So they are still specified to link app's target and included in app bundle.

[image]

Comment: Do you have found any additional documentation about this topic?

Comment: Following the installation instructions on Realm's website does this automatically: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation